# Simple event system using JavaScript (ES5) - JS Custom Event

Tags: javascript, events, dom, event-handling, dom-events

Instructions:

1. make this code work without modifying snippet it in any way.
2. Use only plain old JavaScript and no third-party libraries.
3. Write new code that enables the code below to work properly.

Hint: Feel free to extend native objects... even though it's typically a bad practice.

```js
// Start with an object, any object
var myObject = {};


// Register an event on your object using
// an `on` method
myObject.on('myEvent', function(data) {
    // Log the data passed to the callback
    console.log(data);
});

// Trigger the event using a `trigger` method.
// Include some data when you trigger the event.
myObject.trigger('myEvent', {
    company: 'ABC Corp',
    location: 'WTC Bangalore, IN',
    website: 'http://abc.co'
});
 
// Register a different event
myObject.on('yourEvent', function() {
    console.log('yourEvent fired');
});

// Trigger the new event
myObject.trigger('yourEvent');

// Trigger all existing events using a special
// "star" identifier.
myObject.trigger('*');

// Remove one event by name
myObject.off('myEvent');

// Since we've removed the event, this should
// do nothing
myObject.trigger('myEvent');

// Remove all existing events
myObject.off();

// Since we've removed all events, this should
// do nothing
myObject.trigger('*');
```

Everything else went well. I'm unable to get "arguments" while implementing `myObject.trigger("*")`; unable to read arguments object / parameters while implementing `"*"` and hence throw `undefined`.

[**My JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/aaadesh/3s4utc0y/)

Comment: Is this your homework?

Comment: @hindmost - Your guess is correct, but unfortunately I can't find any answer even after googling around for more than days. I can extend it to add events but couldn't access sequence of event while "*" implement. And hence thought somebody might have better answer for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Disclaimer
I obviously dont know what school you go to or anything, but please don't fool yourself trying to fool your teachers. With a few simple questions they'll know if you understand the material or not, and if you show up with a good answer but no knowledge to back it up, they will know what's up. I'm not accusing you of this, just a friendly word of advice of someone who has had good connections with his teachers after graduating last year ;)*

So, how do we do this? Basically, you will have to add some functionality to the prototype of `object`, at least if you want this to affect **all** objects made afterwards. You can always create your own class and add the function to that prototype if you only want that class to have this functionality.

We need 3 functions added to the prototype, `on`, `off` and `trigger` of course. On top of that we add one extra property called `events`, initially an empty object.
You can look at the raw code for all these in the jsfiddle, I will only go through the structure and logic of the code here.

`events` will hold all the handlers (functions) associated with each event. When adding an event for the first time, we add a `eventName` property to the `events` object, the value for this property is initially an empty array.

`on` will find (or create) the array linked to `eventName` in `events`, and push the function into the array (note we do not call the function at this time, we simply store the reference to the function in the array).

`off` will iterate the array of `eventName`, and if it finds the same function (note the `===`), remove it from the array.

`trigger` will iterate the array of `eventName` and call each function. Note that the function is called with the `this` keyword in the function set to the object, and with the same parameters as the `trigger` function was called (except eventName, the first parameter, which is filtered out). Yes that means you can pass as many parameters as you want to trigger(), and they will all be passed to each handler.

I won't go into detail what things like `splice`, `slice`, `===`, `arguments` and `apply` do exactly, I'm sure you can find more and better information about that elsewhere on the world wide interwebs.

There's a lot more you can do for this, like making the `events` object invisible through some nice uses of scoping, but that wasn't part of the question so I didn't bother with that.

If you have any more questions after looking through this, feel free to ask. I also didn't test it extensively so if you find any bugs, let me know.

EDIT: I didn't read through the comments at first, but I now also added support for the '*' wildcard. Basically the functions now check for the wildcard and will iterate all `eventName`s on the `event` object when removing or triggering. You can also remove all functions for an event by not giving a function or by giving the same wildcard, but with an eventName.

EDIT2: had some bugs running the teacher's code, realized I forgot to check for `hasOwnProperty` while iterating. Look that one up, it's very important when working with prototypes!
I now put in the teacher's code in my jsfiddle, to show you that it works :)

[jsfiddle with own code](http://jsfiddle.net/p8bb8pct/3/)

[jsfiddle with teacher code](http://jsfiddle.net/p8bb8pct/4/)

EDIT3 - about the 'undefined' log.

The teacher's code calls `.trigger` 5 times, and you should see 4 console logs and as far as I can tell, **they are all correct**.Let me run through each trigger, and the subsequent console logs.

1. You add a handler to `myEvent`, which logs the first parameter
2. You trigger `myEvent`, **with parameter** => The parameter (the object), is
   logged.
3. You add a handler to `yourEvent`, which logs a hardcoded
   string.
4. You trigger `yourEvent`, no parameter => The hardcoded string is logged'
5. You trigger `*` **with no parameter**, all handlers run => undefined is logged, since no parameters were given, `data` in `myEvent`'s handler is undefined. The hardcoded string is also logged
6. You remove the `myEvent` handler, trigger `myEvent` and confirm no functions are called
7. You remove all event handlers, trigger `*` and confirm no functions are called from any events.

I honestly don't know what you expected to happen on step 5, since you give no parameter, the `data` is assigned `undefined`, that's intended behaviour.

If you want to merge the data given in step 2 so it remains on the object, then instruct so in your handler. (for example, iterate all properties of `data` and add them to `this`, then log `this`). Right now you simply pass it data, it gets logged, and then thrown away. You can also add a parameter in step 5, and then all handlers will receive it (including the `yourEvent` handlers, but that one doesn't assign nor use it).

Comment: Thanks you, so much for reply, I'm really impressed with brief step by step explanation about how one can add, trigger and remove custom events.
I’m totally agree with the fact that “modifying native object behavior is Evil”; hence added note or hint "Feel free to extend native objects...".
[Here’s my JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aaadesh/3s4utc0y/)
It gives me exactly same response as from `your teacher code`, if you noticed your `"*"` implementation throw `undefined` since it's not able to access arguments object which was original question if you carefully go through my entire question.

Comment: I think I see what you mean, but I don't know why you consider this wrong. I would have answered here but it got a bit too lengty - see my updated answer.

Comment: Also, about modifiying native behaviour: I wouldn't call it evil, but it is definitely dangerous. If you are writing a standalone app (none or minimal 3rd party libraries) then you are in full control and won't cause any issues as long as you do it correct (like we are doing here). In any kind of bigger project the best practice is probably defining your own object class and using `= new MyObject` instead of of `= {}`

Comment: (which you obvioulsy already have under your belt, looking at your code)

Comment: No problem, this was actually really good practice for myself. Thanks for accepting :)

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", displayDate);`

Comment: Thanks for reply @Paul but I'm not looking at creating any dom event. It's custom event `myEvent` which will have handlers like `on` `off` `trigger` etc; which can be easily added using JavaScript `prototype` chain.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.