# onmouseover event does not works on mobile

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, mouseevent, onmouseover

I'm working on the website http://zag-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/website/intime2.html and as you can see there's a responsive image map on the right.

What I need is to enable the `onmouseover` event on mobile too for that picture. In fact, if you check it via mobile what you have (when you touch the single slice) is just a "page refresh". This is the HTML code:

```
    <div class="clock">
            <img class="img-responsive" id="Image-Maps-Com-image-maps-2015-10-01-031428" src="http://zag-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/website/base.png" border="0" width="434" height="420" orgWidth="434" orgHeight="420" usemap="#image-maps-2015-10-01-031428" alt="" />
<map name="image-maps-2015-10-01-031428" id="ImageMapsCom-image-maps-2015-10-01-031428">
<area shape="rect" coords="432,418,434,420" alt="Image Map" style="outline:none;" title="Image Map" href="http://www.image-maps.com/index.php?aff=mapped_users_60334" />
<area  alt="" title="" href="" shape="poly" coords="18,295,124,405,167,310,125,258" style="outline:none;" target="_self" onclick="http://zag-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/website/1.png" onmouseover="if(document.images) document.getElementById('Image-Maps-Com-image-maps-2015-10-01-031428').src= 'http://zag-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/website/1.png';" onmouseout="if(document.images) document.getElementById('Image-Maps-Com-image-maps-2015-10-01-031428').src= 'http://zag-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/website/base.png';"  />
<area  alt="" title="" href="" shape="poly" coords="21,136,19,286,111,245,120,180" style="outline:none;" target="_self" onclick="http://zag-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/website/2.png" onmouseover="if(document.images) document.getElementById('Image-Maps-Com-image-maps-2015-10-01-031428').src= 'http://zag-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/website/2.png';" onmouseout="if(document.images) document.getElementById('Image-Maps-Com-image-maps-2015-10-01-031428').src= 'http://zag-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/website/base.png';"  />
<area  alt="" title="" href="" shape="poly" coords="23,124,135,20,179,124,128,170" style="outline:none;" target="_self" onclick="http://zag-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/website/3.png" onmouseover="if(document.images) document.getElementById('Image-Maps-Com-image-maps-2015-10-01-031428').src= 'http://zag-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/website/3.png';" onmouseout="if(document.images) document.getElementById('Image-Maps-Com-image-maps-2015-10-01-031428').src= 'http://zag-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/website/base.png';"  />
<area  alt="" title="" href="" shape="poly" coords="144,17,298,19,256,123,183,123" style="outline:none;" target="_self" onclick="http://zag-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/website/4.png" onmouseover="if(document.images) document.getElementById('Image-Maps-Com-image-maps-2015-10-01-031428').src= 'http://zag-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/website/4.png';" onmouseout="if(document.images) document.getElementById('Image-Maps-Com-image-maps-2015-10-01-031428').src= 'http://zag-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/website/base.png';"  />
<area  alt="" title="" href="" shape="poly" coords="306,23,413,136,310,178,261,128" style="outline:none;" target="_self" onclick="http://zag-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/website/5.png" onmouseover="if(document.images) document.getElementById('Image-Maps-Com-image-maps-2015-10-01-031428').src= 'http://zag-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/website/5.png';" onmouseout="if(document.images) document.getElementById('Image-Maps-Com-image-maps-2015-10-01-031428').src= 'http://zag-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/website/base.png';"  />
<area  alt="" title="" href="" shape="poly" coords="414,299,416,142,310,182,312,253" style="outline:none;" target="_self" onclick="http://zag-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/website6.png" onmouseover="if(document.images) document.getElementById('Image-Maps-Com-image-maps-2015-10-01-031428').src= 'http://zag-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/website/6.png';" onmouseout="if(document.images) document.getElementById('Image-Maps-Com-image-maps-2015-10-01-031428').src= 'http://zag-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/website/base.png';"  />
<area  alt="" title="" href="" shape="poly" coords="296,413,413,305,309,258,255,307" style="outline:none;" target="_self" onclick="http://zag-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/website/7.png" onmouseover="if(document.images) document.getElementById('Image-Maps-Com-image-maps-2015-10-01-031428').src= 'http://zag-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/website/7.png';" onmouseout="if(document.images) document.getElementById('Image-Maps-Com-image-maps-2015-10-01-031428').src= 'http://zag-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/website/base.png';"  />
</map>
    <p style=" margin-top: 20px; color: #000;" align="left">Ablauf eines Störfalls in einer Käserei –<br>Wir sind “in Time”.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

On mobile doesn't exists mouseover event.

Comment: I know that i've to use ontouch. But i can't find a good guide or tutorial

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly you want to happen when you click on it, but if it isn't important you could use javascript to turn `onmouseover` into `onclick`, or just turn the `onclick="http://zag-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/website/1.png"`into

`onclick="if(document.images) document.getElementById('Image-Maps-Com-image-maps-2015-10-01-031428').src= 'http://zag-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/website/1.png';"`

Comment: What i need is that when you click on the first area shape="rect" coords="432,418,434,420" the http://zag-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/website/1.png as a tooltip. I mean i need the same effect that you an see if you check the website on desktop.

Comment: so if nothin's really suposed to happen when you click on it on nonmobile device, you  could just use the same scrypt after the onclick as after onmouseover, so mobile user can just tap on the "time shapes" to see what's going on

Answer (score 0):

Yah correct, there's nothing called `mouseover` for mobile.

Below resources might help you understanding `events`:

- [W3Schools Events Examples](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events_examples.asp)
- [Know more about JS Touch Events](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/responsive-mobile-friendly-web-design/touch-events-in-javascript.html)
- [Understanding Custom JavaScript Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32435984/design-a-simple-event-system-using-javascript-es5-js-custom-event)
- [Document and Events](http://javascript.info/tutorial/events)

And many more you can find over internet.